# How to integrate pgbouncer-1.4 with PostgreSQL -9.0 database

Tags: database, postgresql, pgbouncer

[enter link description here](http://raghavt.blogspot.in/2011/08/connection-pooling-with-pgbouncer-on.html#comment-form)I'm new to pgbouncer and postgreSQL database. Trying to integrate pgbouncer with postgreSQL database.
After installed successfully pgbouncer, its giving error while starting the pgbouncer.

```
bash-3.2$ ./pgbouncer -d /etc/pgbouncer.ini
2016-03-11 05:18:21.549 25831 ERROR broken auth file
2016-03-11 05:18:21.549 25831 LOG File descriptor limit: 1024 (H:1024), max_client_conn:1000, max fds possible 1010
2016-03-11 05:18:21.550 25831 FATAL @src/main.c:739 in function main(): unix socket is in use,cannot continue
```

Please share some idea here How to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance
Satya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - it looks like you have two issues.

1. Your auth file has errors.
2. The socket you are trying to listen on is in use.

You probably want to:

1. Read the pgbouncer documentation for configuration formats
2. Make sure you have pgbouncer listening on a different socket from PostgreSQL (which I assume is what has happened here).